# Changing the Leftbarbuttonitem Ttitle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am using two view controller. I know that when we move to second view controller, the back button title in the Second View Controller will display the First View Controller Title. Now My first View Controller title is **Registration**, But when I move to the Second View Controller the back should be displayed as "**Home**". I tried using the following code, but it doesn't change.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"Home";
```

Even in the SecondViewController I created my own custom BarbuttonItem like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

But the button looks like a rectangle shape.

Can anyone tell me how to change the Leftbutton item title. ??

Comment: we can do that as "Home", but when you click on that button you will go to back screen "Registration". Is it not a problem for you? and you want the button like rectangle?

Comment: @alishaik786. I mentioned in the question that , I dont want as a rectangle shape.

Comment: @iNoob. yes. I have added in the FirstViewController only. But when i pushed the second view controller, the back button title is displaying as FirstViewController title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you push the new ViewController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
[backButton release];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide BackButton then create your own left UIBarButtonItem

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;


UIBarButtonItem *btn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"YourCustomTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(yourAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btn;
```

If you want to display more UIBarButton in left then you need to create NSMutableArray *arrBarBtn with the capacity then add uibarbutton objects to it.

After that crate UIToolBar then [myToolBar setItems:arrBarBtn];

Final create custom UIBarButton with customView:myToolBar. assign it to self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem. if you need code then I will provide.

Comment: Hiding the backbutton and creating a new barbuttonitem, it will create a rectangular shape button, which i don't want

Comment: You can create your custom UIBarButton. you can create UIButton what shape of type you want then UIBarButtonItem *barBtn=[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:(UIView*)//pass it here

Comment: If my answer is helpful then please up-vote by clicking up arrow and accept it by clicking on checkmark. if you need help let me know.

Comment: you need to code it in your second View controller ViewDidLoad method

Comment: Thank you. Am already using the ToolBar only. Thank you. I have upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also... write this in FirstViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"FirstViewController"];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Registration"];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Try this one